# How to creat a set with elements from either set 1 or set 2 or both?

Tags: java, set

Hey I wanted to ask how I can add elements in a new set that either are in my **set a** or **set b** or both **sets**. This is what I have until now. Would be nice of you could help me.

```
public static Set<String> vereinigung(Set<String> a, Set<String> b) {
        Set<String> setForAB = new HashSet<String>();

        //add elements from a
        setForAB.add(String.valueOf(a));

        //add elements from a
        setForAB.add(String.valueOf(b));

        //elements from both sets
        setForAB.addAll(a);
        setForAB.addAll(b);

        return setForAB;
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you have with your code? Looks like it does what you're trying to do iiuc.

Comment: Return Sets.union(a,b) - you're already doing it but on your own sauce, just remove the first two "String.valueOf" and you'll obtain the same result

Comment: The problem is the return I'm not sure if I should write cases or something like that. Like if this just return elements from set a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track, removed unncessary code from your solution.
This should suffice.

```
public static Set<String> vereinigung(Set<String> a, Set<String> b) {
        Set<String> setForAB = new HashSet<String>();
        //add elements from both sets
        setForAB.addAll(a);
        setForAB.addAll(b);
        return setForAB;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, [Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) can not contain duplicates, so if you want a set C to contain all values from set A and set B, then you simply need to add all elements of A and B. When a duplicate is found, it will simply ignore it and move on. I'm not sure why you are casting your sets to a string, but you can simply add the sets themselves to the new set:

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> c = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
c.addAll(b);
```

Comment: You probably meant c.addAll(b) instead of newSet.addAll(two) which wouldn't compile